# How to start a GtkApplication from inside a gnome-shell-extension?

Tags: javascript, gtk3, gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extensions

My goal is to start a new GtkApplication when the user presses a button in the topbar of Gnome.
The button in the topbar can be done by a gnome-shell-extension, but I have difficulties opening up the GtkApplication.

Therefore, for now the following code should just start the GtkApplication.

Enabling this extension after putting the code inside `~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/test@test/extension.js` always results in a `SIGSEGV` signal of `gnome-shell`.

```
const Lang = imports.lang;
const Gtk = imports.gi.Gtk;
const TestApp = new Lang.Class({
    Name: 'TestApp',
    Extends: Gtk.Application,
    _init: function() {
        this.parent({ application_id: 'testapp.apptesttt' });
    },
    vfunc_activate: function() {
        //this.window.present();
    },
});
function init() {
}
let _app;
function enable() {
    _app = new TestApp();
    _app.register(null);
}
function disable() {
    _app.quit();
}
```

Comment: Instead of running a `GtkApplication`, have you considered simply launching the application in a different process?

Comment: @meskobalazs You mean by forking off another process? How would I do that in javascript?

Comment: If I knew exactly, I would have written an answer :) But GLib and GIO does have an API for that.

Answer (score 1):

I am probably a bit late to the party, but in case someone else ends up here:

The answer most likely lies within `imports.misc.util`:

```
const Util = imports.misc.util;
Util.spawn()
```